# Listing camera folders in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

In previous versions of Windows, there was a "feature" which, after connecting my Sony Camera via the USB cable, showed folders divided by days like this:

Folder1:  2015-08-10
Folder2:  2015-08-11
etc.

But now it shows pure content of the SD card. Meaning:

Folder:  DCIM
Folder:  MP_ROOT
etc.

How can I get the previous folder-view back?

Comment: I think its a camera function rather than windows feature. In my friend's camera, there is an option to set it, you can set the camera to create a folder for storing photos of each day or for a month. Check your camera functions for such options.

Comment: It is possible that Windows 10 ignores my camera settings?

Answer (score 2):

Your camera connects over MTP, and the folder layout is determined by the camera.

There *is* however an option to "group by" (right click, group by and "more") - and one of the options there is "date taken"

[image]

Which seems to do the trick for me

[image]

This works similarly to the group by date option but uses the meta tags

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but it was more convenient just to copy and paste whole folder as it is with videos etc. My camera has not changed, I only changed my OS from win 7, to win 10. May be win 10 ignores that MTP camera setting? On my notebook with win 7 it works as expected.